# Mysql always failed to start in a docker container

Tags: mysql, docker, lamp

I am trying to make a lamp stack using docker.
Here is my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
LABEL MAINTAINER rakibtg
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y apache2 && \
    apt-get install -y mysql-server php5-mysql && \
    apt-get install -y php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mcrypt
WORKDIR /var/www/html
COPY . /var/www/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD apachectl -D FOREGROUND
```

Now once i build the docker image and try to access the mysql using adminer it fails. Here is the screenshot,

[image]

Then i logged in the container shell try to restart mysql but that also fails.

[image]

At this moment i can't understand what i am missing, is there is anything related to docker? However i am new to docker.

I am using Ubuntu 14 and PHP 5.5 intentionally to support some old site

Comment: You can instead decouple the MySQL DB and php-apache services, and `link` these two containers so you can access the DB using its container name.

Comment: Check the server log file. MySQL usually tells you quite detailed why it can’t start

Comment: @spongeworthy At this moment i was trying to put everything in one image, is that is a bad practice in docker implementation?

Comment: @rakibtg Yes it is, and it will be a lot more difficult to debug each service if they're all installed on one container, try using `docker-compose.yml` to orchestrate even your local development environment.

Comment: @rakibtg your way is much harder white decoupling is much easier and less error-prone. Try to learn first.

Comment: Docker containers are not VMs. Consider them as processes. Installing mysql is not as trivial as it might be on an ubuntu VM (with just using `apt-get ...`). See the official MySQL 8.0 [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/fc3e856313423dc2d6a8d74cfd6b678582090fc7/8.0/Dockerfile) to understand what I mean.

Comment: The logic behind Docker is separation of concerns. Start thinking how to achieve your migration by using the official images like [PHP](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/) and [MySQL](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) and making them work together.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions, i was reading the doc and thought a single container is fine for my project, but now i understand :)

Answer (score 2):

Split your services into docker-containers. So one for MySQL, one for PHP, one for Apache/NgInx,....

Add the links within the containers (NgInx/Apache should be able to connect to PHP, PHP should be able to connect to MySQL) and instead of "localhost", use the generated name of the containers (most likely something like "docker_mysql_1")